# Add textview to show the temperature parameter is in (abnormal, normal) and show notification to app user (firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-notifications, real-time-data

[left shown firebase database, right shows the data retrieve from firebase in android studio(want to implement the textView which can shown (abnormal,normal) condition when exceed 30 Celcius)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Es25z.png)

I am currently using firebase database to retrieve real time parameter in Android Studio. I want to use TextView to show the parameters meet the condition by displaying abnormal(once exceed 30) and normal(lower than 30) condition. Any way that can show this.Thanks

```
public class RealtimeData extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference mDatebase;


private TextView mTempView;
private TextView mHumidView;
;

//CHANGE WIFISTATE STARTS
WifiManager wifiManager;
TextView wifiStatusTextView;

//start

//end

Switch wifiSwitch;
//CHANGE WIFISTATE ENDS

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //test dialog out start
    buildDialog(RealtimeData.this).show();
    //test dialog out end
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_realtime_data);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //CHANGE WIFISTATE STARTS
    Toast.makeText(RealtimeData.this,"Make sure device is connected to The internet for latest data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiStatusTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wifi_status);
    wifiSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.wifiswitch);

    if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
        wifiStatusTextView.setText("Wifi status: ON");
        wifiSwitch.setChecked(true);
    }else{
        wifiStatusTextView.setText("Wifi status: OFF");
        wifiSwitch.setChecked(false);
    }

    wifiSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                wifiStatusTextView.setText("Wifi status: ON");
                Toast.makeText(RealtimeData.this,"WIFI may take a moment to turn on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                wifiStatusTextView.setText("Wifi status: OFF");
            }
        }
    });
    //CHANGE WIFISTATE ENDS

    mDatebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Region 1").child("Parameter Reading");
    mTempView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempvalue);

    mDatebase.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot datasnap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String temp = datasnap.child("airtemperature").getValue(String.class);
                mTempView.setText("Air Temperature: " + temp + " *C");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            mTempView.setText("Air Temperature: Error");

        }
    });
```

and xml file here are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#9575CD"
tools:context="com.dropbox.core.examples.android.RealtimeData">


<!--make sure android:id="@+id/include are not appear(automatically) in this 
column below (<include layout)-->
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/datavalue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DATA VALUE"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.193" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lastupdate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Last Update"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.283" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/watertempvalue"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Water Temperature:"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.672" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tempvalue"
    android:layout_width="294dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Air Temperature:"
    android:textColor="#5D4037"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.54" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/humidvalue"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
    android:text="Air Humidity:"
    android:textColor="#004D40"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.667" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/datevalue"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Date: "
    android:textColor="#3E2723"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.385" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timevalue"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:text="Time:"
    android:textColor="#3E2729"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.457" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pHvalue"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="pH: "
    android:textColor="#795548"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.732" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/levelvalue"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Water level: "
    android:textColor="#424242"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.927" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/CO2value"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CO2 :"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#01579B"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.792" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:text="Abnormal"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tempvalue"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.54" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Wi-Fi status:"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.807"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.104" />

<!-- Start of Text TVOC button
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TVOCvalue"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TVOC: "
    android:textColor="#3E2723"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.836" />

    End of Text TVOC button-->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TDSvalue"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:text="TDS :"
    android:textColor="#212121"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.867" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/wifiswitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.162" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

edited part shows here

```
if (Float.valueOf(temp) < 30) {
        mTempView.setText("Air Temperature: " + temp + " *C" + " Normal");
    } else {
        mTempView.setText("Air Temperature: " + temp + " *C" + " Abnormal");
        public void showNotification(View view)
        {

          NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
          builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.impressive);
          builder.setContentTitle("Notification Alert");
          builder.setContentText(" Air Temperature abnormal!!");
          Intent intent = new Intent(this,RealtimeData.class);
          TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
          stackBuilder.addParentStack(RealtimeData.class);
          stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
          PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
          builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
          NotificationManager NM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
          NM.notify(0,builder.build());

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot datasnap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        String temp = datasnap.child("airtemperature").getValue(String.class);
        if (Float.valueOf(temp) < 30) {
            mTempView.setText("Air Temperature: " + temp + " *C" + " Normal");
        } else {
            mTempView.setText("Air Temperature: " + temp + " *C" + " Abnormal");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yup, its worked, now I am facing another problem. I would like to add notification in android once the air temperature is abnormal. 
Thing like showNotification. I did try  from other tutorial regarding to notification alert once air temperature abnormal  but it seems it cant work. Any ideas for that? i did edit the question and provided notification trial which I have done before.

Comment: Thanks , marked. btw I already post another questions  regarding to the problems in "linked questions" , can you giv me a favor ?

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look and if I know the answer I'll write it right away. Cheers!